# difference between reverse saturation and leakage current

Tags: diodes, leakage-current

I searched a lot but I didn't find any answer

For a PN junction diode is the leakage current when the diode is reverse biased

Equal to the reverse saturation current??

If they are not equal so where does the excess current come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In an ideal diode, they are the same. The diode equation is

$$I = I_s \left[\exp\left( \frac{qV}{n k_B T}\right) - 1\right]$$

so if you apply a strong reverse bias (\$v \ll 0\$), then the reverse current will be very close to \$I_s\$, the saturation current.

In a real diode, there may be other leakage paths aside from through the PN junction itself that allow current to pass, so the leakage current may be greater than the saturation current. For a diode mounted on a PCB, there could be additional leakage due to surface contamination.

Comment: Thank you sir,So there is no equation that could give the real leakage current through a diode?or It depends on the manufacturer?

Comment: Yes, it depends on proprietary information of the manufacturer, the exact geometry of the device, the materials used, etc. On a PCB it could also depend on things like surface contamination.

Answer (score 0):

A quick answer to your question is no they are not the same.  On a IV Characteristic curve of a PN junction diode, you will generally have a very low reverse bias current (Leakage current).  This current is said to be 1uA in the most extreme conditions for a silicon small signal diodes.

[image]

The 'Reverse Saturation Current' is also called the 'Zener Breakdown' or the 'Avalanche Region'.  This current will drastically increase as the Reverse Breakdown Voltage is achieved and most likely destroyed your diode unless you have a high resistance in series to limit the current flowing through the diode in breakdown conditions.

If you are looking at a specifications for a PN junction diode, I would assume the reverse saturation current is specified as a maximum.  This will give you guidance on what resistor you should put in series with the diode to protect your circuit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,But my text book says that the reverse saturation current is in the Order of 10^-12A and is independent of the reverse voltage.the saturation reverse current is the Term(Is) that appears in the Shockley diode Equation......  I = Is(exp(Vbe/Vt)-1)

Answer (score 0):

On a standard diode. When its reverse bias the depletion region expands. Tis effect causes the diode to become a capacitor (there are special diodes that are enhanced to work like this and used as a variable capacitor). The reverse bias leakage current is the insulation breakdown of this diode in its capacitance state. The depletion breakdown voltage is the voltage potential at which the diode will conduct in reverse bias. Since the standard pn junction diode is not constructed like a zener diode (zener diodes actually have pn-pn arrangements on its die internally), it will short out in its typical circuit design due to the lack of current limiting. Zener diodes have to be current limited (usually by a resistor in series) so it can maintain this reverse bias voltage potential without the current running away causing the diode to short.